# Number of classes in large projects

Tags: oop

I'm just wondering about large projects - say an airlines reservation system, how many classes/objects it is likely to have.

Objects: customer, airplane, airport, route, ticket, order.  That's about all I can think of.  The project will probably be hundreds of thousands of lines of code, so are there likely to be more classes (that do un-object related things)?

If so, how many classes are there likely to (roughly) be?  How many objects (as per my list so not 10,000 customer objects, how many different *names*) are there likely to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's really no magic formula for calculating optimal number of classes. The architecture you described above may create a very, very simple airline reservation system. As you continue to refactor, add more features, and accommodate special cases, you could end up with *many* more classes, e.g., MealPreference, CouponCode, Terminal, Gate, Airline, Baggage, BaggageTransfer, RainCheck, FlightUpgrade etc.

As you should (if you want to be agile), only code exactly what you need at the time, planning ahead for ease of extension. However, any project is going to grow in unanticipated ways over time.

Comment: Your response makes me wonder what an object is supposed to correspond to. I guess the answer to that is: "whatever you want it to."

Answer (score 3):

For a real world airline reservation system? Thousands. Easily.

I'd guess around half of them are "infrastructure" classes - mostly related to persistence, logging, integration, etc. Maybe a few hundred domain classes (Airline, Airplane, Flight, Passenger, FrequentFlyer, MaintenanceSchedule, WeatherDelay, etc). And then another half of them would be UI related - controllers, views, view models, etc. to support both customer and internal apps.

Answer (score 1):

The number of classes will be only statistical and it knowing it won't help you to establish any best practice, but I would say it can go to thousands of classes.

What it's important is to keep in mind the best practices and naming conventions, it is important to have a good package structure and name your classes according to its purpose, also keep in mind a high level of cohesion for your classes.

So other than satisfying your curiosity the number doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The number of classes is really relative to the design patterns and architecture you build.

For instance, with a simple console application that adds two numbers together, you can have anywhere from 1 to 10 (rough guess) based on the implementation and abstraction used.

You really can't judge how many "objects" an application is going to contain, without knowing the architecture and patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is very dependent on a lot of things; code language, application architecture, number of 3rd party extensions (which typically contain a lot of classes that don't actually ever get called by the app, but are included with .dll or .jar files), and a lot on the habit of the developer and if they tend to use giant monolithic classes, or break down everything into an interface, abstract, simple/stub, and real implementation.

However if your just looking for statistics, I was recently working on a large project for General Motors that had I'd say roughly 3000 classes, plus 200 JSP pages, and a few dozen CSS and JS files supporting the UI. Plugged into that you have DB drivers, Spring framework, a couple apache commons libraries, Hibernate ORM, Mule, JSTL, probably some other core components... the web server itself...

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on the abstraction you use. In my experience, the closer you follow the problem domain (the closer you try to make your code read like what a business person would say), the more classes you'll have.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers you've received are wise: basically, "It depends."

But in another sense, there is an optimal number of classes you should have for a given number of methods; that is, given a number of methods, there is a specific number of classes (within a non-hierarchical encapsulation context, and to a close approximation) which minimises the potential structural complexity of those methods. (The actual number is given by the second law of encapsulation, and is equal to the square root of the number of methods divided by the number of public methods per class).

So then the question becomes: how many methods will you need? By analogy to the above, in which methods are encapsulated within classes, so blocks of code are encapsulation within methods, and so the number of methods is fixed by the same second law above.

So then the quesiton is: how many code blocks will I have?

That's answered by the other responses you've received: it depends.

For more, see Encapsulation Theory here:
www.EdmundKirwan.com

Regards,

Ed.